# How to prevent to reset or clearing the django form fields if any error occurs during submit?

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I am using django **registration-redux** for user registration.
When i enter a same userid it shows error and the clears all the input fields of the form. how to prevent that error should occurs but input fields shouldn't get cleared.

```
<form method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab" for="id_username">Username *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input  name="username" id='id_username' class='form-control' placeholder='Username' minlength="5" maxlength="15" type='text' required></div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab" for="id_email">E-Mail *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10" >
                    <input class='form-control' name="email" id='id_email' placeholder='user@mydomain.com' pattern="(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.com$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.org$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.co\.in$)" maxlength="200" type='email' required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab">Password *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="password1" id="id_password1" placeholder="Password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" type="password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab2">Password Confirmation *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="password2" id="id_password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" type="password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
 <button  type="submit" value= "register">Register</button>
</form>
```

should i use java script or what should help me?

Comment: How do you validate that same userId was entered?

Comment: i have use a django package all the views are inbuilt . i have just render the form

Comment: when any x user enter same userid it shows error (user is already exits) and clear form input fields

Comment: i want to prevent this form clearing

Comment: any help brk please your reputations are good

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your form should retain the entries. From what I can infer, it seems that you might not in your template you are not making use of `form` passed by the view.

Here is an example on how you can update the template:

```
<form action="/action/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form">
            <br />
            {{ form.username}}
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Now in your action view you can easily pass the variables in your form. Something like :

```
def action(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print("form.errors:", form.errors)
    else:
        form = CustomForm()
    ResponseDict = {"username": username}
    return render_to_response("UserName.html", ResponseDict, 
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

For more reference - [Displaying form using template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)

The main essence is in you going to your view and then making the necessary calls. Please do note that wherever you are rendering the html you are also passing the form values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to solve this problem in front end becoz i have use a package to register a user i don't have view of it

Comment: Oh. Thats even more simple. You could just define it in storage variable or cache it. Could you tell me what language are you using in your front-end?

Comment: html5  and bootstrap

Comment: hey Pansul any help

Comment: I would suggest you use Jquery here. And store your responses in caches. What that would do is if the value is not set, it would fetch the value from the cache and update your form. Does that help?

Comment: but how to use jquery

Comment: jQuery or angular both seem like a suitable solution here. I would go for angular so your field has `ng-model` set on it. If you are familiar with angular this should be easy. You then put a watch on the submit button and save the value in the cookie. Whenever you hit submit you check whether the $scope value has changed or not. If it has been removed you update it with your cookie's value.